# is it possible to use cell array in matlab function block in simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

i have a Structure that describe my fuzzy system and I'm gonna to use it on MATLAB Simulink in general for fuzzy type 1 i could use fuzzy logic controller block BUT i have fuzzy type 2 and a structure describe it's membership functions and other attribute, i have to use it on simulink but matlab function block in simulink can't generate code for  a cell array and i receive error.
so i ask you guys please help me:
is it possible to use cell array in matlab function block in simulink?

Comment: building the simulink model of max number of an array without using minmax block

Answer (score 0):

The [MATLAB Function](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html) block supports all the data types that Simulink supports, see [Data Types Supported by Simulink](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/working-with-data-types.html#f14-90488), and so I believe cell arrays aren't supported. However, you should be able to use the [Fuzzy Logic Controller](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/fuzzy/fuzzylogiccontroller.html) from the Fuzzy Logic Toolbox.

Comment: thanks for answering! <br/>
yes cell array and structures doesn't support in MATLAB Function, Fuzzy Logic Controller Support just .fis files! i mean matlab fuzzy files, but my fuzzy controller is type2 that .gfs file type... now I'm trying to edit this gfs files and remove all cell array type data!! this is a taught work to do ...